# `clone` doesn't add element `after`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clone element and add it after onther elelment. This code supposed to do that but not work

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-add-faq-row', function(){
    var tl = $('.faq-container:last');
    tl.clone().after(tl);
});
```

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ux0a4vqa/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-add-faq-row', function(){
    var tl = $('.faq-container:last');
    tl.clone().insertAfter(tl);
});
```

or you need to do it like this with **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-add-faq-row', function(){
    var tl = $('.faq-container:last');
    t1.after(tl.clone());
});
```

In your code you are trying to insert element after the cloned element which is not yet part of the dom.

**UPDATE :** or more better and easy way using  **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** with callback

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-add-faq-row', function(){
    $('.faq-container:last').after(function(){
        return $(this).clone();
    });
});
```

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy : missing jQuery library in your fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/ux0a4vqa/2/

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add `tl` *after* the clone, but the clone doesn't exist anywhere yet. You need to do it the other way around:

```
var clone = tl.clone();
tl.after(clone);
```